# time() function in php says current time is 1970

Tags: php, macos, apache, time, xampp

I am running XAMPP on mac.

I have a very simple script:

```
<?php
echo time();
```

always returns time in the 1970.

example: 1475044574 (Edit: 1475137157)

I tried setting the timezone in php.ini and then calling date_default_timezone_get() and it returns the correct set value.

I tried adding SetEnv TZ MyTimezone to httpd.conf (at the bottom of the file) and it did not work.

I also tried setting the timezone in php with date_default_timezone_set() and though it sets successfully, time is still in 1970.

I tried the same script on MAMP and still the same problem.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: But your example (1475044574) is Wed, 28 Sep 2016 06:36:14 GMT

Comment: Time in 1970 will never be `1475044574`

Comment: What makes you think that time is in 1970? Hint, It isn't

Comment: The most likely issue is that you are making a mistake when trying to convert the unixtimestamp into a actual date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time function is returning proper unix timestamp you are doing mistake in converting time into proper format. 1475044574 means Wed, 28 Sep 2016 06:36:14 GMT which is correct.

You can convert time as you want. refer [date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

check this sample code :

echo date('M j Y g:i A', 1475044574);

Bro, as per PHP manual php.net/manual/en/function.time.php time() function returns seconds not miliseconds. Please check timestamp your timestamp on this site epochconverter.com.

Comment: hold on, that's weird. I was testing the script the last two days, and converting the time at currentmillis.com. The time was always in 1970. I ran the script one last time to copy the time here for the question, without checking. It suddenly is the correct date?

Comment: Bro, as per PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php time() function returns seconds not miliseconds. Please check timestamp your timestamp on this site http://www.epochconverter.com/.

Comment: Oh well this is awkward. I read the docs for this function quite a few times in the last two days and never noticed that. Can you post it as an answer please?

Comment: brainiac, I have edited my answer you can mark it as answer. 

Thanks, 
Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

`time()` function `returns current Unix timestamp`. So, your `1475044574` is a timestamp.

Using `date` function you can see that this is a timestamp of (some variations with timezones, results may vary):

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1475044574);
// 2016-09-28 02:36:14
```

If you convert this timestamp to some string representation and get something like `00-00-1970` - you obviously do the conversion **wrong**.